# How do I keep this image in the center of the window?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a hangman-like game; for that, I need all the different stages of the man to be visualized, hence images. I want the entire tkinter window to be an image, when I change the size it pushes the image right.

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x350")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1600, height=900)
canvas.pack()
img = PhotoImage(file="4.png")
canvas.create_image(470,190, image=img, )
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

If canvas is bigger than window then when you resize then it show more canvas but and it can looks like it moves image.

But if you use smaller canvas then `pack()` will try to keep centered horizontally. And if you add `pack(expand=True)` then it will try to keep it centered vertically.

In example code I added red background to window to show where is canvas

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x350")

root['bg'] = 'red'

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="lenna.png")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=350)
canvas.pack(expand=True)
canvas.create_image(300, 175, image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

Before resizing:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

---

If you want to draw only image then you could use `Label(image=img)`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x350")
root['bg'] = 'red'

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="lenna.png")

label = tk.Label(root, image=img)
label.pack(expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Before resizing:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

---

**BTW:**

`tkinter` can `bind()` some function to event `<Configure>` and it will execute this function everytime when you resize window (and/or move window) - and this function may also move or resize image in window.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def resize(event):
    global img
    
    lower = min(event.width, event.height)
    #print(event.width, event.height, 'lower:', lower)
    
    new_image = original_image.resize((lower, lower))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_image)  # need to assign to global variable because there is bug in PhotoImage
    
    label['image'] = img

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("350x350")
root['bg'] = 'red'

original_image = Image.open("lenna.png")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original_image)

label = tk.Label(root, image=img)
label.pack(expand=True)

root.bind('<Configure>', resize)

root.mainloop()
```

Before (it resized image at start to fit window):

[image]

After (it resized image to fit window):

[image]

[image]

[image]